# Full Screen Cover Flickers when IOS app is opened

Tags: swift, swiftui

So basically in my SwiftUI app, there is a login screen and if you are already logged in then you move on to the `HomeView()`. If not, then you stay on the `LoginView()`. However, every time I open the app, the .fullScreenCover flickers before the `.onAppear{}` statement realizes it's time for the cover to disappear. Here is the code:

```
struct HomeView: View {

@ObservedObject var fireViewModel = FirebaseViewModel()

@State var loginPresented = true


var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            
            Text("You are already Signed in")
            
            Button(action: {
                fireViewModel.signOut()
            }, label: {
                Text("Sign Out")
            })
            
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        if fireViewModel.signedIn {
            loginPresented = true
        } else {
            loginPresented = false
        }
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $loginPresented, onDismiss: nil, content: {
        LoginView()
    })

}
```

}

Comment: Try setting `@State var loginPresented' to false to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the

```
@State var loginPresented = false
```

In the beginning solves the problem.